# How to capture response from a server in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Consider that we have a server which when triggered with a URL (with data within the URL), the Server responds by creating a PDF file.

In PowerBuilder tool, we trigger the URL via PostURL():

```
int ll_return
inet_base = CREATE inet
ll_return = inet_base.postURL('http://server:8080/postRender?', Blob, header string, port#, internetData)
```

In the postURL argument, the Blob is the data that was appended to the URL. The data is converted to blob and then passed as an argument.

The details of the postURL function is in below link:
http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/CCJCIIFD.htm

Consider that the server returns **404** code with some message like:    **File not found!**

I need help to write the PowerBuilder code to capture the response of the server. Currently, since we are using PostURL function to trigger POST request, in return I am getting only integers such as:

- 1 Success
- -1 General error
- -2 Invalid URL
- -4 Cannot connect to the Internet
- -5 Unsupported secure (HTTPS) connection attempted
- -6 Internet request failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into this issue, I find out that it is possible to capture the response message coming from the server.

Taking the reference of the above code:

```
int ll_return
inet_base = CREATE inet
ll_return = inet_base.postURL('http://server:8080/postRender?', Blob, header string, port#, internetData)
```

The last argument in the PostURL function is an object called InternetData. The InternetData is a object which contains a function named as internetdata(blob data).

The response message from the server is captured in the variable **blob data**.
We need to convert the data to String as follows:

```
is_data = String(data, EncodingANSI!)
```

The variable `is_data` will contain the HTML script which consists of the response message from the server.

Method to create an internetResult type of user object:

- Click on File > New
- Select PBObject Tab
- Select Standard Class and Click OK
- Select the Standard Class Type as internetresult and click on OK.

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

The  object passed into the postURL function is basically a callback object. The callback function on that object is InternetData(blob Data).

So you need to create a descendant from the InternetResult class and implement the InternetData function to process the received data block as you see fit.